# Why does a MySQL 5.7 left join to an empty set cause the query to perform worse?

Tags: mysql, query-optimization

I have a query that left joins one table to a subquery, and although the subquery returns an empty set due to a where condition, the overall query still takes significantly longer with the join than without it, even if I consider the time it takes for the subquery to run. Any ideas why this is happening? Details below

Query:

```
select Address.*
from Address
left join (
    select lotNumber, max(jobId) as id
    from Address
    where jobId is not null
    group by lotNumber
) latestJob on latestJob.lotNumber = Address.lotNumber
```

Schema:

```
CREATE TABLE `Address` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `streetNumber` varchar(45) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `street` varchar(45) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `lotNumber` varchar(45) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `jobId` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `idx_Address_lotNumber` (`lotNumber`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1032717 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
```

Explain:

```
+----+-------------+-----------------+------------+-------+-------------------------------+-------------------------------+---------+---------------------------+---------+----------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table           | partitions | type  | possible_keys                 | key                           | key_len | ref                       | rows    | filtered | Extra       |
+----+-------------+-----------------+------------+-------+-------------------------------+-------------------------------+---------+---------------------------+---------+----------+-------------+
|  1 | PRIMARY     | Address         | NULL       | ALL   | NULL                          | NULL                          | NULL    | NULL                      | 1027850 |   100.00 | NULL        |
|  1 | PRIMARY     | <derived2>      | NULL       | ref   | <auto_key0>                   | <auto_key0>                   | 183     | Address.lotNumber         |      10 |   100.00 | NULL        |
|  2 | DERIVED     | Address         | NULL       | index | idx_Address_lotNumber         | idx_Address_lotNumber         | 183     | NULL                      | 1027850 |    90.00 | Using where |
+----+-------------+-----------------+------------+-------+-------------------------------+-------------------------------+---------+---------------------------+---------+----------+-------------+
```

Currently the `Address` table has about 1M records, but `jobId` is null for all of them so the left joined subquery returns an empty set.

The subquery takes ~0.07 second to run by itself, however the entire query takes ~2.22 seconds. The query without the subquery takes ~0.07 second. It seems that when joining to an empty set, the entire query should just take ~0.07 + ~0.07 = ~0.14 second, so where are the extra 2 seconds coming from? It seems like something inefficient is happening in the join operation. Anyway to improve this?

Thanks

Comment: How many rows of data returned when you run the code?

Comment: @FanoFN, I suppose it's about 1M rows as the OP mentioned `Currently the Address table has about 1M records` and the left join should only  return data from the left table due to the failed join condition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a short answer: add an index for your `jobId` column.I have a similar table named `proctable`, which has 1.4 m rows generated through a procedure. While the table name and column names differ from yours, the structure is alike( with the unnecessary columns omitted):

```
 CREATE TABLE `proctable` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `num` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `jid` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `idx` (`num`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1429159 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

The `id` has  values range from 1 to 1429158, while the `num` is randomly generated using function `rand()` which is from 1 to 10000. The `jid` has all rows set to null. The original query (without indexing column `jid`)executes like this:

```
select * 
from proctable t1
left join (select  num, max(jid) as id
    from proctable
    where jid is not null
    group by num
) t2 on t1.num = t2.num;
-- 1429158 rows in set (7.08 sec)   

explain select * 
from proctable t1
left join (select  num, max(jid) as id
    from proctable
    where jid is not null
    group by num
) t2 on t1.num = t2.num;

-- here is the execution plan :

| id | select_type | table      | partitions | type  | possible_keys | key         | key_len | ref           | rows    | filtered | Extra       |
+----+-------------+------------+------------+-------+---------------+-------------+---------+---------------+---------+----------+-------------+
|  1 | PRIMARY     | t1         | NULL       | ALL   | NULL          | NULL        | NULL    | NULL          | 1426920 |   100.00 | NULL        |
|  1 | PRIMARY     | <derived2> | NULL       | ref   | <auto_key0>   | <auto_key0> | 5       | testdb.t1.num |      10 |   100.00 | NULL        |
|  2 | DERIVED     | proctable  | NULL       | index | idx           | idx         | 5       | NULL          | 1426920 |    90.00 | Using where |
```

Then we index the `jid` column and do it again.

```
create index jidx on proctable(jid);

-- the execution plan has changed:
explain select *  from proctable t1 left join (select  num, max(jid) as id     from proctable     where jid is not null     group by num ) t2 on t1.num = t2.num;
+----+-------------+------------+------------+-------+---------------+------+---------+------+---------+----------+--------------------------------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table      | partitions | type  | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref  | rows    | filtered | Extra                                                  |
+----+-------------+------------+------------+-------+---------------+------+---------+------+---------+----------+--------------------------------------------------------+
|  1 | PRIMARY     | t1         | NULL       | ALL   | NULL          | NULL | NULL    | NULL | 1426920 |   100.00 | NULL                                                   |
|  1 | PRIMARY     | <derived2> | NULL       | ALL   | NULL          | NULL | NULL    | NULL |       2 |   100.00 | Using where; Using join buffer (Block Nested Loop)     |
|  2 | DERIVED     | proctable  | NULL       | range | idx,jidx      | jidx | 5       | NULL |       1 |   100.00 | Using index condition; Using temporary; Using filesort |
```

By using jidx as the key, the DERIVED one using range as the type instead of index  has drastically reduced the rows anticipated from 1+ million to 1. Let's execute the query.

```
select * 
from proctable t1
left join (select  num, max(jid) as id
    from proctable
    where jid is not null
    group by num
) t2 on t1.num = t2.num;
-- 1429158 rows in set (3.73 sec)
```

Note: This is done on my lab VM which has a measely 4G physical ram. By adding an index for `jid` , it nearly reduced the response time by half. Additionally, if you change the outter join to inner join or straight join, the discrepancy is huge.

```
select *  from proctable t1   join (select  num, max(jid) as id     from proctable     where jid is not null     group by num ) t2 on t1.num = t2.num;
-- Empty set (0.00 sec)

explain  select *  from proctable t1   join (select  num, max(jid) as id     from proctable     where jid is not null     group by num ) t2 on t1.num = t2.num;
+----+-------------+------------+------------+-------+---------------+------+---------+--------+------+----------+--------------------------------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table      | partitions | type  | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref    | rows | filtered | Extra                                                  |
+----+-------------+------------+------------+-------+---------------+------+---------+--------+------+----------+--------------------------------------------------------+
|  1 | PRIMARY     | <derived2> | NULL       | ALL   | NULL          | NULL | NULL    | NULL   |    2 |   100.00 | Using where                                            |
|  1 | PRIMARY     | t1         | NULL       | ref   | idx           | idx  | 5       | t2.num |  146 |   100.00 | NULL                                                   |
|  2 | DERIVED     | proctable  | NULL       | range | jidx,idx      | jidx | 5       | NULL   |    1 |   100.00 | Using index condition; Using temporary; Using filesort |

explain  select *  from proctable t1   straight_join (select  num, max(jid) as id     from proctable     where jid is not null     group by num ) t2 on t1.num = t2.num;
+----+-------------+------------+------------+-------+---------------+------+---------+------+---------+----------+--------------------------------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table      | partitions | type  | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref  | rows    | filtered | Extra                                                  |
+----+-------------+------------+------------+-------+---------------+------+---------+------+---------+----------+--------------------------------------------------------+
|  1 | PRIMARY     | t1         | NULL       | ALL   | idx           | NULL | NULL    | NULL | 1426920 |   100.00 | NULL                                                   |
|  1 | PRIMARY     | <derived2> | NULL       | ALL   | NULL          | NULL | NULL    | NULL |       2 |    50.00 | Using where; Using join buffer (Block Nested Loop)     |
|  2 | DERIVED     | proctable  | NULL       | range | jidx,idx      | jidx | 5       | NULL |       1 |   100.00 | Using index condition; Using temporary; Using filesort |

select *  from proctable t1   straight_join (select  num, max(jid) as id     from proctable     where jid is not null     group by num ) t2 on t1.num = t2.num;
-- Empty set (2.91 sec)
```

Comment: Amazing! That did it. Any ideas why this works or related documentation describing this behavior though? Judging by the explains it looks like the optimizer is incrementing through the entire table and trying to join each row to a non existent row from the subquery or something? And having an index helps it realize it doesn't need to do that since once it's found a record with a non-null job id it knows there are no more with null job ids so it stops iterating? Totally speculating here.